# In-App Purchase Validation

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am securing that my binary's  In-App Purchase. Now I am able to send base_64 transaction.receipt  data to my server with jSon and my server pushes to directly to Apple service and getting result if it's real payment or not.

I am working on  Sandbox environment right  now and everything going well. But when my binary will approve, My binary will be in realtime payment statement and Sandbox will no longer exist. In my service i can switch url's wheter is it sandbox or not.

But when my app going to be in InReview Statement , Review team will also test in sandbox ? What if they will put me in real time payment status and get test my app like that. They will get error because of my service pushes the data to the  sandbox environment ...

Is there anyway to get understand that my binary is in Sandbox statement or not with programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

The review process tests against the sandbox.  You should submit your app with the provision of a developer hold so you can then switch your servers to production before you release the app.

Comment: That means , in my server, The URL will stay for sandbox testing  till my app will approve and ready for sale statement ? After ready for sale ( Green dot ) I can change it to production URL ? or I have to do it just after my app status will change Waiting For Review to In Review ?

Comment: You can change it at any time to be honest.  But the receipts you get will be sandbox receipts until you release the app.  At that point the endpoint will change to Apple's production servers automatically.  Be aware that any sandbox receipts you have will come back invalid when you move to production.

Comment: So, is there any way to reach endpoint URL in SKPayment class ?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's [**In-App Purchase Programming Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/AppReview.html) describes the environments that are used during development, review and production along with the suggested approach from App Developers

[image]

As you can see from the diagram, during review purchases are made against Apple's test (sandbox) server, but since the binary that is being reviewed is the binary that will be released to the store, that binary must be configured to use your production server (or production URL if you have only a single server).

In order to ensure that receipts are still validated correctly, the guide advises:

> When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code “Sandbox receipt used in production”, validate against the test environment instead

Answer (score 1):

[image]I think you can't test a real purchase (with real money)

If your purchase works against the sandbox, it should work against prod as well.

[IAP Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html)